# cant send data using ajax showing some localhost alert(php)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I wrote a script which doesn't send the data from the AJAX to the PHP file. and showing error in alert box[image: here is the actual error that i got]

`HTML`

```
      <form id="contact-form" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="single-contact-form">
          <div class="contact-box name">
          <input type="text" name="name"  id="name" placeholder="Your Name*" style="width:100%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="single-contact-form">
    <div class="contact-box name">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email*" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="single-contact-form">
     <div class="contact-box name">
       <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Your Mobile*" style="width:100%">
   </div>
  </div>
<div class="single-contact-form">
    <div class="contact-box name">
     <input type="text" name="password"  id="password" placeholder="Your Password*" style="width:100%">
    </div>
</div>
                                    
  <div class="contact-btn">
     <button type="submit" name="register" id="register" class="fv-btn" >Register</button>
                                    
    </div>
</form>
```

`JS`

```
 <script>

 $(function(){

      $("#register").on("click",function(e){
           
        e.preventDefault();

           var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var phone = $("#phone").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();
           
             if( name == "" || email == "" || phone == "" || password == ""){
              alert("all field required");
             }else{
                  
            $.ajax({
                data: "ajax.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:{cname:name,cemail:email,cphone:phone,cpassword:password},
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    $("#contact-form").trigger("reset");
            }
        });
    }
    });
   

}); 
   
</script>
```

`php`

```
<?php 

include "../inc/database1.php";



        $name = $_POST['cname'];
       
        $email = $_POST['cemail'];
        
        $phone = $_POST['cphone'];
         
        $password =$_POST['cpassword'];
 

       

       
                
   $sql = "INSERT INTO   tbl_user (name,email,phone,password) values('$name','$email','$phone','$password')";
    
     $value = $this->db->conn->prepare($sql);
     $data = $value->execute();
      if($data == TRUE){
         echo "successfully register";
          }else{
            echo "not sent";
           }
      
?>
```

Comment: are you sending the request to the same page?

Comment: incidentally your code is vulnerable to SQL injection - use a prepared statement instead of embedding variables in the sql. Also do not store a `plain text` version of the user's password - use `password_hash` to hash the password and then, to check(login etc), use `password_verify`

Comment: That's not an error.  That's HTML.  Does that HTML response *contain* an error that you're not showing us?  What does it contain?  What is the actual error?

Comment: Unless your `database1.php` script was creating that HTML output already, I don’t see where it should be coming from - nothing in the PHP code you have shown looks like it would generate any output of that kind. First guess here would be, that you are not sending your AJAX request to the correct URL in the first place.

Comment: It is very strange to see a html tag <php. Check the source where this code is generated...

Answer (score 0):

you have to do some changes in your ajax as you do not mention the url of ajax where it post the data and the variable data is reinitialised.
**try this:**

```
$.ajax({
     url: "ajax.php",      // its url you need to add
     type: "POST",
     data:{cname:name,cemail:email,cphone:phone,cpassword:password},
     success: function (result) {
          alert(result);
          $("#contact-form").trigger("reset");
     }
});
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: try to study and remember point about ajax and jQuery. and Welcome.